# reading header from a UTF8 CSV file using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to read a CSV file in Ruby 1.9.3 (I am not using Rails.)

```
sessions = CSV.read("c:/scripts/ruby/testcsvencoding.csv", :headers => true, 
:encoding => "UTF-8") 

sessions.each do | session |
  p session['col1']    <-- does not work
  p session[0]   <--- works
end
```

The file contains:

```
col1, col2
a,1
b,2
```

I saw what *seems like* "[Avoding “Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8″ with Ruby and CSV files](http://blog.psy-q.ch/2011/09/avoding-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-with-ruby-and-csv-files/)", but it may not be the same problem as mine.

When I try the workaround there I get an error.

Is there any way to solve this?  Is this a known problem?

This is on Windows

Comment: This works just fine on my OS X machine, maybe this is a bug in Ruby on Windows? What is the exact error?

Comment: did you save the csv file as utf8

Comment: `session = CSV.read(file, headers: true, encoding: 'bom|utf-8')`

Answer (score -1):

That error means there's a bad utf-8 byte sequence in your data. If that bothers you, fix the data. Otherwise try ascii-8bit.

Comment: Not sure if I miscommunicated.  I don't get an error.  If I refer to the first columns using session['col1'] it doesn't work.  The second column and other work fine.  For the first column i need to use session[0], i.e., I can't use the column name

Comment: Ok but if you're data were as you supposed, the code would work. Therefore something is wrong with your data.

Comment: a utf8 file adds a few additional bytes at the beginning of the file.  I think as a result, ruby/csv, misunderstands the first column name.  This is not a problem with my data, i can reproduce it with any data.

Comment: No, that's simply not true.

Comment: is true, too!!  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding I also realized i can save the file without the BOM.  After that the reading works.  btw, i could be wrong.